# Sharing memory among a parent and child process in Solaris (in C)

Tags: c, solaris, shared-memory

I am just looking for a simple tutorial/example to put me in the right direction, I cannot seem to find a good simple one.

I am looking for a tutorial that explains how to share memory (not using pipes and files, but actual memory) between a parent and a child (using fork) process in UNIX (Solaris) in C.

I really appreciate your help,

Thank you very much,

Jary

Comment: Have you tried goggle at all? Here's the first hit: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html

Comment: Thank you. I have looked at google, but only got complex examples. This one is the best I have found, but I was wondering if anyone had any better ones.

Comment: I have a doubt that this example is actually for Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to options:

- You can allocate and attach the shared memory first and then do the fork.
- You can allocate the shared memory, fork the child process and then attach to the shared memory in both processes.

The first option is probably easier. It could look as follows:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

....

int size = 32000;

/* allocate and attach shared memory */
int shmID = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size, 0600);
void* shmPtr = shmat(shmId, NULL, 0);

/* fork child process */
pid_t pID = fork();
if (pID == 0)
{
    /* child */
    ... do something with shmPtr ...

    /* detach shared memory */
    shmdt(shmPtr);
}
else
{
    /* parent */
    ... do something with shmPtr ...

    /* detach shared memory */
    shmdt(shmPtr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one subtle question: with this method, is it possible that the parent checks the shared memory when the child exists please? By that I mean, the child calls exit(), but I would want to return from 0 to 4 values. Would it be possible for the parent to use sigaction() and read the shared memory in the function call (from the interrupt when a child exists) please?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.